# PayPal IPN Curl issue

Tags: php, ssl, curl, paypal

Upon till recently: late September PayPal IPN has been working fine. But, recently it has stopped. Checked code and it is all fine.

```
    try {
        $listener->requirePostMethod();
        $verified = $listener->processIpn();
        mail('###@###.com', 'what is the verified value?', $verified);

        } catch (Exception $e) {
        mail('####@####.co.uk', 'error', $e->getMessage());

        error_log($e->getMessage());
        exit(0);
        }
```

This block of code after I go through the checkout process will try the processIPN method. However, the Catch part gets executed. In the email i get the error message,

> cURL error: [60] SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed.

I guess PayPal may have updated their security measures or such. How can I fix this?

Comment: Include your CURL request please

Comment: http://pastebin.com/L4K3QRdF

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions her to upgrade https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1766&viewlocale=en_US&direct=en

TEMPORARY WORKAROUND: Migrate to ipnpb.paypal.com. This endpoint will remain on SHA-1 until Q2 2016 and can be used as an alternate IPN processing point.